# Appending text to input field on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, input, append, submit

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Salmon"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Trout"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Halibut"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Crab"  />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Users will be inputting a number for the value. When they submit the form I want to append the title of each input to the submission. So if the user input "5" for the first input field, it would submit the value as "Salmon - 5".

How could I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working here http://jsfiddle.net/NLtS9/6/.
Change type="submit" to type="button"

```
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('input[name="order[]"]').map(function () {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('title') + ' - ' + $(this).val());
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! What if an input box is left empty, how difficult is it to make this function not do anything for empty no-value inputs?

Comment: You can just put the line that is assigning the value inside a conditional that checks to see if the value is empty. I've added this to the fiddle. <http://jsfiddle.net/NLtS9/8/>

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('input[name="order"]').map(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title') + ' - ' $(this).val());
    });

    ('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: My form submits ok with this, however the title and '-' are not appended to the input fields. It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @RobertE That was because the form was submitting without executing this script. You could change remove the `type="submit"` attribute off your button and try this instead.

Comment: I've updated per your suggestions and it is not capturing anything but the original value input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('button').click(function(){
      $('input').each(function(index,data) {
        $(this).val( $(this).attr('title')+"-"+$(this).val());
       });
    })
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be causing an error on the entire form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Make your button a simple button not a submit button and then do

```
$('button').click(function(){
      $('input[name="order"]').map(function () {
         $(this).val($(this).attr('title') + ' - ' $(this).val());
      });
      $('form').submit();
    })
```

Comment: The form submits but it does not append the title and the ' - '. It doesn't seem to be working.I also did make sure that my button did not include the type attribute.

Comment: If you do not include the type attribute in the button then it will default to submit. So the type SHOULD be there and it should be set to button. i.e. --> type="button"

Comment: Yes you should explicitly set the type attribute to 'button'

Answer (score 0):

Use the `submit` event handler in jQuery. This updated code work in my localhost

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function (ele) {
        ele.preventDefault(); // don't submit multiple times
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(_,e){
             var old_val =  $(e).val();
             $(e).attr('data-old', old_val).val($(e).attr('title') + '-' + old_val);
        });

        this.submit(); // use the native submit method of the form element
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(_,e){
             $(e).val($(e).attr('data-old'));
        });
    });
});
```

HTML Ireplace `button` by `input` and show the `action` explicitly.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Salmon"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Trout"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Halibut"  />
    <input type="text" value="" name="order[]" title="Crab"  />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Form submits as normal but there is nothing appended to the value.

Comment: I'm following the code exactly as directed and it really is not passing anything but the entered value. So strange.